# File Sharing website with a permanent link structure

Tags: upload, cloud, sharing

I am wondering if I can find a file sharing website that gives you a permanent link that follows the same structure 
the point is
if the account that uploaded the file is closed we can easily make a new username 
and do a research and replace in the database to replace the old links with a new one

for example

sitex.com/user1/filename.xxx

sitex.com/user2/filename.xxx

and so on 
it doesn't matter what criteria the site uses 
as long as it is the same across all files except for the file name or maybe the folder name

does anyone know of a similar site?

Comment: sounds legit...

Comment: it is legit, the data is just some scanned pdfs from our college, however it is huge around 5000 Files